# How to remove an indefinite prefix?

Tags: python

I have input where I need to remove the first indefinite part of string.

possible input:

```
/a (some optional text)
/a@w (some optional text)
/an (some optional text)
/an@w (some optional text)
/am (some optional text)
/am@w (some optional text)

/b (some optional text)
/b@w (some optional text)
/bn (some optional text)
/bn@w (some optional text)
/bm (some optional text)
/bm@w(some optional text)

c...
```

I need output just '' or (some optional text) if exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[regex](https://regex101.com/r/6TlkA9/1)

```
import re

def remove_indefinite_part(input_string):
    # Define the regular expression pattern to match the first indefinite part
    pattern = r'^\/[a-zA-Z]+(@[a-zA-Z]+)?\s?'

    # Find the first match using the pattern
    match = re.search(pattern, input_string)

    if match:
        # Remove the matched part from the input string
        modified_string = input_string[len(match.group()):].strip()
    else:
        modified_string = input_string

    return modified_string

# Test the function with example inputs
inputs = [
    '/a (some optional text)',
    '/a@w (some optional text)',
    '/an (some optional text)',
    '/an@w (some optional text)',
    '/am (some optional text)',
    '/am@w (some optional text)',
    '/b (some optional text)',
    '/b@w (some optional text)',
    '/bn (some optional text)',
    '/bn@w (some optional text)',
    '/bm (some optional text)',
    '/bm@w (some optional text)'
]

for input_str in inputs:
    result = remove_indefinite_part(input_str)
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
(some optional text)
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at the pattern you prompted you could split the string at the space character ' ' and return the second item in the split array.

```py
input.split(' ')[1]
```

Comment: Ye, but sometimes (some optional text) not exits and there error. In this case I need just '' output.

Comment: But if the optional text includes spaces, this will fail; you can edit your answer to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

A regex should do the trick; this one removes all character from the start of the string up to (including) the first space:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'^[^ ]* ', '', my_input))
```